# int i=int(); what happens in D?

Tags: d, primitive-types, value-initialization

Consider following program (See live demo [here](http://ideone.com/RPfWno))

```
import std.stdio;
void main()
{
   int i=int();
   writefln("i is %d",i);
}
```

In language like C++ the statement **`int i=int();`** is known as value initialization. For the type **`int`**, value initialization basically ends up being zero initialization. If I am not wrong C++ standard guarantees that it gives me zero always. But is D language contain feature like value initialization as we have in C++? Is it necessarily give me a zero on all D compilers & on every environment where I compile & run above D program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a variable is declared in D, it is always set to its 'default initializer', which can be manually accessed as `T.init` where `T` is the type (ex. `int.init`). The default initializer for integer types is `0`, for booleans `false`, and for floating-point numbers `NaN`.

So you don't even need to assign to a variable for default initialization; just declaring it is fine. `int i;` will always be zero until set to something else.

Default initialization can be explicitly disabled by initializing the variable to `void`; for example, `int i = void;`.

Comment: But http://www.tutorialspoint.com/d_programming/d_programming_variables.htm says that "For definition without an initializer: variables with static storage duration are implicitly initialized with NULL (all bytes have the value 0); the initial value of all other variables is undefined.". & in my program variable is having automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 2):

In D any value is initialized, it will here always give the default value for an integer: 0. It is way safer than in C++ where initialization occurs only if it can be done at no cost.

Comment: Only if it can be done at no cost? Tell that to `std::vector`.

Comment: @chris What type from C++ has to do with D?

Comment: Note: you can use `int i = void;` when you want uninitialized value.

Comment: @sigod, I gave a counterexample to the statement in the answer: *It is way safer than in C++ where initialization occurs only if it can be done at no cost.*

Comment: @chris I will admit my ignorance of std::vector internals, C++ is complex and I merely wanted to give a rule of thumb :)